# C#: KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary

Tags: c#, string, dictionary, keynotfoundexception

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<String, EngineProperty> kvp in propertyDict)
{
    Debug.Log(kvp.Key.GetType()+" : "+ kvp.Key+ " "+ mainText.text.GetType()+ " "+ mainText.text);
}
slider.value = propertyDict[mainText.text].GetSpeed();
```

5 items get printed from the foreach loop. The below code is one of them

```
System.String :   Piston   System.String   Piston
```

`Piston` is the key which I'm looking for

But right below the for loop,

when I use this

```
slider.value = propertyDict[mainText.text].GetSpeed();
```

I get this error

```
KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
```

But key was printed in the for loop. I don't get it.
This is how I initialized

```
public Dictionary<String, EngineProperty> propertyDict = new Dictionary<String, EngineProperty>();
```

I have tried replacing everything with `String` with `string`, and still, it doesn't work.

What do I do?

Comment: I suspect the key in the dictionary has a space at the end of it, and `mainText.text` doesn't. You should check that, then work out what you want to do about it. (When printing arbitrary strings, if you put a `'` at the start and end of them, or something similar, it really helps to make any leading or trailing spaces clear.)

Comment: Or just check length of both.

Comment: Looks like 2 spaces /left/right padding for some reason on the keys. We'd need to see how the KeyValuePairs are constructed. Maybe key it off an enum that represents the set that your currently populating the strings with?

Comment: One may have spaces (database or lookup key).  You may need to use Trim() when saving to dictionary or lookup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jon Skeet said in his comment, the issue looks to be extra spaces.  If you look at the first part of the string `System.String :   Piston`, there are 3 spaces between the colon and Piston, but you have only put one in your separator.  That means there are 2 spaces at the beginning of Piston.  Similarly, there are 3 after Piston, so that means the actual string is  `Piston` .  For the `mainText`, you have a similar 3 spaces before Piston, but none after, according to the string you posted.  This would make `mainText` to be   `Piston`, which doesn't match.